# Pointers to structs being passed to function

Tags: c, pointers, persistence, struct

This is a stripped down version of my program. I need to pass a pointer to pointers of structs to a function, modify the structs within the function, and have those changes persist. The function declaration must stay the same.

Currently I can modify the data within the function, but once returned to main, no changes were made.

Thank you for your help.

```
int main()
{
    struct node** HuffmanNodes;
    read_Huffman_encoded_data(&HuffmanNodes);
}

void read_Huffman_encoded_data(**HuffmanNodes)
{
    Huffman_node = (node**)malloc(sizeof(node*)*(*number_of_nodes));

    int index;
    for(index=0; index<*number_of_nodes;index++)
    {
        Huffman_node[index] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        Huffman_node[index]->first_value=1;
        Huffman_node[index]->second_value=2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer typing problem. I'm surprised that it even compiles since `&HuffmanNodes` is of type `node***`.

Try this:

```
void read_Huffman_encoded_data(struct node ***HuffmanNodes)
{
    *Huffman_nodes = (node**)malloc(sizeof(node*)*(*number_of_nodes));

    int index;
    for(index=0; index<*number_of_nodes;index++)
    {
        (*Huffman_nodes)[index] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        (*Huffman_nodes)[index]->first_value=1;
        (*Huffman_nodes)[index]->second_value=2;
    }
}
```

You also have some naming mismatches (which I fixed), I hope those are just typos from stripping down the program.

EDIT: Alternative Method

```
int main()
{
    struct node** HuffmanNodes = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node) * (*number_of_nodes));
    read_Huffman_encoded_data(HHuffmanNodes);
}

void read_Huffman_encoded_data(struct node **HuffmanNodes)
{
    int index;
    for(index=0; index<*number_of_nodes;index++)
    {
        Huffman_nodes[index] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        Huffman_nodes[index]->first_value=1;
        Huffman_nodes[index]->second_value=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I changed to your suggestion, the for loop changes the values of the structs the first time through, but seg faults when it tries to loop through again.

Comment: Just to clarify: So it's getting through 1 iteration of the for-loop. Then crashing on the second?

Comment: Yes. Also, not to be picky, but it would be easier if the function declaration stayed the same, with **HuffmanNodes. If the & in the calling of the function is the problem, that can be changed.

Comment: I you don't want to use ***HuffmanNodes, then you will need to allocate it in main. Lemme make my edit. As for why it's crashing in the loop, I have yet to figure that out yet.

Comment: I cant allocate it in main because the omitted parts of this function are to read from a file and initiate the structures from the file data.

Comment: If you can't allocate it in main, then what you're trying to do is not possible. You basically have 3 options: 1. Allocate inside main and pass it in. 2. Allocate inside function and write to a `node***`. 3. Change the return value to a `node**`, then allocate inside the function and return it.

Comment: Well thank you for trying! Would declaring it at struct node*** HuffmanNodes in main make any sense?

Comment: No it wouldn't. Try drawing a diagram of your pointers and what everything points to, and it should make things a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
    struct node** HuffmanNodes;
    read_Huffman_encoded_data(&HuffmanNodes);
}

void read_Huffman_encoded_data(**HuffmanNodes)
{
    Huffman_node = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)*(number_of_nodes));

    int index;
    for(index=0; index<*number_of_nodes;index++)
    {
        Huffman_node[index] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        Huffman_node[index]->first_value=1;
        Huffman_node[index]->second_value=2;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I ran this, it still didnt show changes when returning to main.